# What's the practical difference between Ajax (formerly AJAX) and AJANE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

On February 18th, 2005, Jesse James Garrett gave the acronym **AJAX** (*Asynchronous Javascript and XML*) to an increasingly popular approach which harnessed the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

**See:** http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications/

Over a relatively short time JSON became the preferred data-interchange format and AJAX (now effectively *AJAJ*) became **Ajax** (a name - rather than an acronym - for one approach to asynchronous data retrieval).

But what about **AJANE** *(Asynchronous Javascript and Nothing Else*)?

```
function retrieveMyAsynchronousData() {
    var myAsynchronousData = document.createElement('script');
    myAsynchronousData.setAttribute('src', '/data/my-asynchronous-data.js');
    document.body.appendChild(myAsynchronousData);
}

myElement.addEventListener('click', retrieveMyAsynchronousData, false);
```

It's beyond question that **Ajax** is the industry standard approach, not **AJANE** - but why? Is it faster, more secure, more optimised?

- What are the *practical advantages* of **Ajax** over **AJANE**?
- Why is the former a much more established approach than the latter?
- When developing, why should I use one approach over the other?

---

**N.B.** *Please note, I am not asking for opinion or preference. I am trying to understand if there is an explicit, real-world, technical justification for deploying the `XMLHttpRequest` object over and above simply building a new `<script>` and adding it to the DOM.*

Comment: how do you pass data to server and retrieve data from server using AJANE?

Comment: I'm gonna throw a number out there, but I suspect it's realistic.  About 99% of AJAX calls are not getting Javascript.  They're getting data from a server application (or pushing data *to* a server application).

Answer (score 3):

AJANE (a term I've never heard of before today and which I can't find any reference to on Google) is more commonly known as JSONP. It:

- Requires the creation of a global variable to handle the response (well, that applies to normal JSONP. Your approach seems to involve the response including everything internally instead of being a simple function call that introduces the additional problems of:)

  - Multiple requests to the same endpoint have to fetch all the logic to handle it each time
  - The calling function is limited in what contextual information it can supply to globals and strings
- Does not provide any information about the status of the response (e.g. you can't detect a 404 or 500 error)
- Depends on injecting software into the page instead of data, which means you must absolutely trust the provider of the data
- Is limited to making GET requests